# Error when trying to execute a binary compiled in a Kali Linux machine on an Ubuntu system

Tags: linux, ubuntu, security

I compiled a python script using pyinstaller in a Kali Linux machine and the compilation was successful and the binary was built . However , when I try to execute this binary on a Ubuntu machine I get the following error :
[2664] Error loading Python lib '/tmp/_MEI5jZUdD/libpython3.11.so.1.0': dlopen: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.36' not found (required by /tmp/_MEI5jZUdD/libexpat.so.1)

I far as I understand there is a compatibility issue as Kali’s GLIBC version is 2.36 whereas Ubuntu ‘s is 2.35 . Is there any way to fix it ? Ideally, a GLIBC downgrade in Kali Linux Machine ( which is my main one) would  be useful as each binary I compile there would not have any compatibility issues when running on other Linux machines such as Ubuntu’s system . What do you think ? What should I do?

I tried fully upgrading both machines but this did not help

Comment: Just use a docker.